# Using einsum without explicit replication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have a matrix A of shape (n, n) and another matrix b of shape (p, n). I need to get a matrix C such that

```
C[i] = (A * b[i, np.newaxis, :]) * b[i, :, np.newaxis]
```

I'm currently doing that by doing np.matlib.repmat(A) and then using np.einsum as follows

```
A1 = np.matlib.repmat(A, p, 1).reshape(p, n, n)
C = np.einsum('ijk, ij..., ik... -> ijk', A1, b, b)
```

But I can see that creating A1 is a waste of resources as it's just using the same values over and over. Is there anyway I can do this without creating the intermediate matrix A1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,kij,kij->kij',A,b[:,None,:],b[...,None])
```

Comment: To sum it along axis 1 I just have to use 'ij, kij, kij -> kj' right?